# How to export .csv file from python and using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export some filtered data from Python using Pandas DF to `.csv` file (Personal Learning project)

Code : `df5.to_csv(r'/C:/Users/j/Downloads/data1/export.csv')`

```py
Error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jansa\PycharmProjects\bbb\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    df5.to_csv(r'/C:/Users/jansa/Downloads/data1/export.csv')

  File "C:\Users\jansa\PycharmProjects\bbb\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3551, in to_csv

    return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
  File "C:\Users\jansa\PycharmProjects\bbb\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1180, in to_csv
    csv_formatter.save()

  File "C:\Users\jansa\PycharmProjects\bbb\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 241, in save with get_handle(

  File "C:\Users\jansa\PycharmProjects\bbb\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 697, in get_handle

    check_parent_directory(str(handle))

  File "C:\Users\jansa\PycharmProjects\bbb\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 571, in check_parent_directory

    raise OSError(rf"Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '{parent}'")
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '\C:\Users\jansa\Downloads\data1'
```

I am researching, but cannot pinpoint the error.

Comment: The slash at beginning of the path must be removed.

Comment: This worked, such an error to have missed. But will remember for sure for future. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

`df.to_csv(r'C:\path\to\directory\filename.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in Linux/Mac environment path separator is `'/'` but in windows, it is `'\'`. Also, the absolute path starts with `'/'` in Linux/Mac, while in windows, it starts with `/` So, using arguments in `to_csv` with `C:\Users\j\Downloads\data1\export.csv'` will resolve your issue.

In addition, if you want to get rid of such situations, you can do this:

```py
import os
path = os.path.join('.', 'export.csv') #will save the file in current directory
```

Also, this returns the os path separator:

```py
print(os.sep)
```